# Struggling to iterate over an object with an array of string

Tags: php

Im' trying to iterate over an object with an an array of string in it but I'm struggling to do it

Output of the **var_dump** of the object I'm trying to iterate:

```
object(fooClass)#88(2) {
    ["property1:protected"]=> string(3) "foo"
    ["property2"]=> array(2) { 
                    ["foo1"]=> string(4) "foo1" 
                    ["foo2"]=> string(4) "foo2"}
}
```

(**Edit**)But when I try to use an arrayIterator to iterate over the object with this code:

```
$obj = new ArrayObject($value);
$it = $obj->getIterator();
echo "iterating over: " . $obj->count() . " values <br />";
while ($it->valid()){
    echo $it->key() . "=" . $it->current() . "<br />" ;
    $it->next();                    
}
```

I have this **output**:

```
iterating over: 1 values
*property1=foo
```

**Edit:** What I'm expecting is something like that:

```
iterating over 3 values
*property1=foo
*foo1=foo1
*foo2=foo2
```

Comment: You need to use a loop, take a look at the link: http://php.net/manual/pl/arrayobject.getiterator.php

Comment: yeah I forgot the loop but the output stays the same, it iterates only on 1 value

Comment: Your array has two key with one string and another array, So you need to check for array and then again the loop. A loop inside a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop of loop here. Your array has sub array, so you need to loop twice. Your first loop goes through first array and then check if the value is array or not,if it is an array then you need to loop again for inner value.

**Example:**

```
$array = array('property1' => 'foo',
               'property2' => array('foo1', 'foo2')
          );

$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($array);

$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();

while($iterator->valid()) {
    if(is_array($iterator->current())){
        $arrayobject_2 = new ArrayObject($iterator->current());
        $it = $arrayobject_2->getIterator();
        while($it->valid()) {
            echo $it->key() . ' => ' . $it->current() . "\n";
            $it->next();
        }
    } else
        echo $iterator->key() . ' => ' . $iterator->current() . "\n";        
   $iterator->next();
}
```

Working link: https://3v4l.org/1eS3Q

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($it->valid())
{
    $key = $it->key();
    $value = $it->current();

   // ...

   $it->next();
  }
```

use a loop to iterate and loop will terminate when `it->valid()` returns false.